# apache2 core dump not generated

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, core-dump

I am trying to solve the following error in my apache2 error.log file.
I use Debian Jessie 8 up-to-date with apache 2.4.10 from repo.

> [Tue May 31 16:35:21.951165 2016] [core:notice] [pid 6926:tid 140394522146688] >AH00052: child pid 6929 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

This happen when a user connect to the website with an SSL client certificate. Everything works fine except we got this message every time.

To solve this, I try to generate a core dump from apache2. I followed the debian documentation :

> mkdir /tmp/apache-coredumps/
>
> chmod 755 /tmp/apache-coredumps/
>
> chown www-data:www-data /tmp/apache-coredumps/

add this to my apache2.conf

> CoreDumpDirectory /tmp/apache-coredumps

Execute the following command :

> ulimit -c unlimited
> /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Then I reproduce the error, but /tmp/apache-coredumps/ remain empty.
User permission seems ok to me.

Any idea ?

Comment: are you running `abrtd`, as it will take over the dump. I know that `systemd` will use a private `/tmp` in `/var/tmp` for apache. I presume you are not using `systemd`, but perhaps something similar configures it.

Comment: You should check that actual `httpd` processes followed the `ulimit` setting and have both soft and hard `Max core file size` in their `/proc/pid/limits` set to `unlimited`.

Comment: And I do not think that `ulimit` shell builtin takes cmdline and runs it with changed limits.

Comment: There are also other requirements that process must meet to dump core files, for example, calling `setuid` and brothers or being traced by `ptrace` makes process undumpable in some cases.

Comment: @meuh I'm using systemd, but /var/tmp/is empty. I am not using abrtd.

Comment: @siblynx apache2 pid report : Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes, should I alter the soft limit ?

Comment: Yes you should. Run `ulimit` as `sh -c 'ulimit -c unlimited; exec /etc/init.d/apache2 restart'`

Comment: @siblynx still report 0

Comment: Verify that it actually sets limit: `sh -c 'ulimit -c unlimited; cat /proc/self/limits'`. It should read both `unlimited`. If it's not, then apache tries to mess with it himself.

Comment: If using systemd, and not using abrtd, then beware that systemd will manage the core file. See `coredumpctl`.